# What is the default username for logging in to AWS EC2 Linux instances via SSH?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I recently became responsible for administering several Amazon Web Services Elastic Cloud Computing instances, some of which run Ubuntu and some of which run Amazon Linux. I have the key pair as a `.pem` file. What is the username I should use when connecting via SSH?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is different for different distributions.  The default user for Amazon Linux is **ec2-user**.

The default user for Ubuntu is **ubuntu**.

This is documented at amazon:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html

Comment: Perfect. Knowing that, `ssh -i mykey.pem ec2-user@myinstance.amazonaws.com` got me in.